# Scroll to anchor after jquery.load

Tags: jquery, load, anchor

There's placeholder on the page that is loaded asynchronously using jQuery load method. Page URL might have anchor and I want to scroll to the anchor after content is loaded. What is the best way to do that?

Problem is similar to this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/goto-anchor-after-load
But I don't like the solution. May be someone has and better ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about scrolling with famous **[ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)** plugin?

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, just don't want to depend on extra plugins for pretty simple stuff.

Comment: To be fair, I agree with Sarfraz and the solution is fine. Perhaps you can examine the source of the ScrollTo plugin and see if it inspires you. Either way, I'm in favor of his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this old question, because I had the same problem. I came up with a solution which doesn't need the ScrollTo plugin.

You can use the jQuery.load complete callback function, which executes when the request completes

```
complete
Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
A callback function that is executed when the request completes.
```

For example

```
$("#content").load("mypage.html", function () {
   //Load completed, scroll to element
   $("#content").animate({
      scrollTop: $("#myElement").offset().top
   });
});
```

Might help people with the same problem in the future.